# android how to delete a created bimap

Tags: android, bitmap

In my activity a bitmap is there and it is moving on screen (through Accelerometer).
I put a condition there if that bitmap reach some specified co-ordinate on screen then it should not visible more or it will permanently delete.

How can I do that. Give me an way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hide a `bitmap`, you can call the method `setVisibility(View.xxx)` on your view (probably an ImageViewer,

where *xxx* can be `GONE`, or `INVISIBLE`.

To destroy it, just call `yourbitmap.recycle();`